# ¿Como puedo ejecutar función luego de incluir una página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Estoy trabajando con **ng-include** de angular 1.6, pero necesito ejecutar una función luego de que el archivo termine de cargar.

he intentado con onload, pero no se me da, adjunto código.

```
<div id="mainMenu" ng-include="" src="'mainMenu.php'" onload="finishIncludeElement('coursePage','mainMenu')" class="animated bounceInRight">
</div>
```

y en jquery

```
function finishIncludeElement($currentId,$nextId)
{
    console.log('Angus');
}
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error esta en el llamado de la función, en el html estas haciendo una llamada a una función angular, pero la tienes como una función jquery, lo que debes hacer es pasar la función a tu controlador angular.

Quedaria algo como

```
$scope.finishIncludeElement = function($currentId,$nextId)
{
    console.log('Angus');
}
```

Ten en cuenta que debes agregarlo en el controlador sobre el que estas trabajando actualmente.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Y si necesitas llamar mas de una función?

Comment: en el onload agregas la función que deseas llamar, agregas un punto y coma y luego agregas la otra función siendo siempre una función $scope.